# JavaFX TableView: remove/disable scollbars from the table(using a ScrollPane instead)

Tags: java, javafx

I have two tables, of which I would like to connect the scrollbars, so they can be scrolled simultaneously. As far as I know the binding of the `TableViews` own scrollbars is not possible(correct me if I´m wrong), so i decided to wrap each `TableView` in a `ScrollPane`.

However the scrolling of the table is still set to the `TableView` own scrollbars.

Beneath is a basic code example. As you can see, the bidirectional binding of the `ScrollPane` scrollbars works. However the data in the table is uneffected by this, due to the problem I described above(main control is `TableViews` own Scrollbar).

Can someone help me out on this? I would like to move through the `TableView` with the `ScrollPane` scrollbars, instead of using `TableViews` scrollbars(since I can´t bind them).

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
    private TableView<Person> table2 = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
                    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
                    new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
                    new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
                    new Person("Michael", "Brown")
            );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(300);
        stage.setHeight(1000);

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setPrefWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setPrefWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

        table2.setItems(data);
        table2.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(table);
        sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
        sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);

        ScrollPane sp2 = new ScrollPane(table2);
        sp2.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
        sp2.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);

        sp.setHmax(3);
        sp2.setHmax(3);
        sp.hvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(sp2.hvalueProperty());

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(sp, sp2);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to bind the scrollbars this way :

```
void bindScrollBars(TableView<?> firstTable, TableView<?> secondTable, Orienatation orieantation){
    ScrollBar firstScrollBar = null;
    ScrollBar secondScrollBar = null;

    for (Node node : firstTable.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
            if (node instanceof ScrollBar && ((ScrollBar) node).getOrientation().equals(orientation)) {
                firstScrollBar= (ScrollBar) node;
            }
    }

    for (Node node : secondTable.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
            if (node instanceof ScrollBar && ((ScrollBar) node).getOrientation().equals(orientation)) {
               secondScrollBar = (ScrollBar) node;
            }
     }

    if(firstScrollBar != null && secondScrollBar != null) { firstScrollBar.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(secondScrollBar.valueProperty()); }
```

For me it works fine, and you can bind it both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that your `VBox` is not scaling correctly with the scene, which means that your `ScrollPane`s will never be smaller than their content. You can fix this by changing this:

```
((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);
```

to this:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
```

You will also have to remove your previous declaration at the beginning of `start`:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group()); //Remove this line
```

Now your `ScrollPane`s scale properly with your scene. However, you still need to bind their `vvalue`s so that they match vertically. Add this line below where you bind their `hvalue`s:

```
sp.hvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(sp2.hvalueProperty());
sp.vvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(sp2.vvalueProperty()); //Add this line
```

Now your scrolling works properly:

[image: working scrollbars]